# How to create a local git repository and manage with SourceTree?

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I am new to git (although I work before with perforce and svn) and I would like to source control a Unity project but I don't want to host it anywhere online.
I work on the project alone but I use normally two different computers in different locations. In the past I had a SVN repository in a USB drive and use to update / commit from the local versions of the project in each computer.

Since I never used git before and I want to lear, I am trying to do the same thing (I know you are not supposed to use git in this fashion, but I definitely don't want to host my project in any online server).

After reading quite a lot about git, I think I had a decent grasp on how it is different from SVN. I´ve been following this tutorial on achieve my goal:
http://dexterlin.com/tag/git/

I have a local git project in my desktop, and then using the terminal (I work on MAC) I created a bare repository in the desktop in a different folder.

The problem comes when I try to have SourceTree to recognize the bare repository, I couldn't achieve that.
But also I am a bit confuse, I can creare two different folders/respositories in my computer and link them to SourceTree, however SourceTree doesn´t let me push from one to the other, howcome?

I want to use SoruceTree since I need a Windows/Mac client to handle git on the different computers.

So here are the questions:
- What I am trying to do is possible at all in git?
- How do I get SourceTree to point at the bare repository I created?
- Copying the bare repository into a USB drive would work to later pull from another computer repository?
- How do I get SourceTree to let me push/pull from the bare local repository into my local repository?

Many thanks in advance!! Any help will be very appreciated :)

Comment: You can't work into a bare repository, that's just the format of git repository to serve as common/central repository. You could just push and pull from it from your personal repository. And also you can't push to a none-bare repository from another repository.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Philippe, I thought I could push from one non-bare to another (i.e. user 1 pushing to user 2 or vice versa). I'll keep it in mind and use the bare repository as the main updated version to pull from / push to from my two user non-bare repositories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your bare repository to your USB device (say, mounted on `Z:\` or `/Volumes/MyUsbDevice/`), or create a new bare repository there. (I just wanted to point out that you can always move your repositories around)

```
$ cd /Volumes/MyUsbDevice/
$ mkdir myNewGame.git
$ cd myNewGame.git
$ git init --bare
```

The bare repository contains the history of your project in Git's binary format and your files are nowhere to be found there. That's probably why SourceTree is confused.
What you need to do is create a *clone* of this repository on the machine where you want to work:

On Windows:

```
$ git clone Z:\myNewGame.git myNewGame
```

On mac:

```
$ git clone /Volumes/MyUsbDevice/myNewGame.git myNewGame
```

Or you can do that to in Sourcetree, just pass it the location of your git repository on your USB device.

If you browse to `myNewGame/.git/config` you will see a section like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = /Volumes/MyUsbDevice/myNewGame.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This is where Git stores the information about your *remote* bare repository and that's why it's important that you always mount it on the same folder/letter in the future.

You can then work with Sourcetree, `pull` will get changes from your USB device, `push` will write them to your USB device.

You will have the full history in three locations, you mac, your windows and your USB device. Your USB device needs to be connected only when you want to perform fetch or pull or push.

So you're rather safe since your history is distributed, but I would still advise you to take regular backups of your bare repository.

Comment: That worked great! Thanks a lot Thibault D. for your help and taking the time to explain it properly - really appreciate it. Yep definitely I'll do backups from the repository oftenly.

Comment: @thibault >"The bare repository contains the history of your project in Git's binary format and your files are nowhere to be found there. That's probably why SourceTree is confused."No!Because that is store the same way in a personal repository and SourceTree is able to read it. That is just that ST fail to detect that's a bare repository (the cause is not the format. Nearly the only difference is the lack of working directory). GitExtensions, Another GUI on Windows do it well.

Comment: But I thought online repositories like BitBucket or GitHub are essentially bare repositories and SourceTree is able to detect them, right? Sorry if I am mistaken on this I am completely new to git and just trying to learn :)

Comment: The online repositories on BitBucket or GitHub are probably bare ones although there is no way for us to check so and it does not really matter. You can clone a bare repository into a non-bare repository and the other way around, it does not matter. The bare repository is enough to save the history of your project. The non-bare repository contains the history + a local copy on your filesystem so that you can work on it.